# Does findAll() on a repository fetch all results before returning?

Tags: spring-data-cassandra

Does `findAll()` on a repository fetch all results before returning? The reason I am asking this is because I got `OutOfMemoryException` when calling it on a rather large dataset (~15 GB on disk). Since it returned an `Iterable<T>` I was expecting it do background batching so that I easily could iterate over the entire dataset.

I guess I'll file an issue on the JIRA if the method does not allow larger query results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, we do not support paging, but would like to explore supporting it.

Please enter an issue at https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACASS

-matthew